# Accessing a virtual linux machine using another linux virtual machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, centos7

I need to test and practice ssh(secure shell deamon) in linux,to do that I have configured a centOS 7.0 virtual machine and a ubuntu 12.10 virtual machine in VMware 12.0 workstation.(My host machine is running windows 8)
I powered up both virtual machines and try to connect ubuntu machine from centos machine using `ssh root@IPaddress` .but I continue to get the error

> ssh: connect to host 92.222.136.30 port 22: Connection refused

I don't know it is possible to ssh connect in that manner.But I don't no any other way to test and practice this stuff.What is the wrong I have done here?or is there any easy method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the network configuration.
I would suggest using Bridge adapters on both machines.
If you are trying for a static IP on both then I would suggest try the following configuration

1. VM-1: two NIC cards. NIC-1 on NAT and NIC-2 on bridge (static IP)
2. VM-2: two NIC cards. NIC-1 on NAT and NIC-2 on bridge (static IP)

I would also suggest trying to allow port 22 on firewalld or Iptables or you can completely disable firewalls by using the following commands since you are testing

**systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl disable firewalld**

also check if the port 22 is open, check with

**netstat -tulnp | grep -i 22**

and see I presume you are running centos as a server [infrastructure server/ or a full installation]. If on minimal install of centos you would have to install the openssh server using **yum -y install openssh-server**

I hope this helps, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

telnet IPaddress 22 ( check if ssh port is open )

check your ssh port using command **netstat -plantu**

turn off the firewall or flush IP tables

use command **ssh root@IPaddress -p 22** (if you use custom port then change value 22 to your port number)